# Best performance by calculating KPI in ETL or SSAS?

Tags: ssas, etl, kpi

I want to create KPI for financial mart. I can create KPI in SSAS and I can calculate KPI in ETL process. Which way has better performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performance wise its always good to do most of the processing at ETL level so that when browsing the cube less processing is involved, and users can get results faster, On the other hand having columns in fact table will increase database size, and cube processing time. It all depends on your business case, see link for more insights.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/6a3d2a3f-8a32-4ce5-8828-2998ccea6ab1/best-practice-for-calculations